# Mifare DESFire EV3 set of VC Configuration key fails with Integrity Error (0x1E / 30 dec)

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare, desfire

I'm trying to set the VC (Virtual Card) Configuration key on a **Mifare DESFire EV3** card.

The VC Configuration key has the key number 0x20 (32 dec) as per AN12752
MIFARE DESFire EV3 feature and functionality comparison to other MIFARE DESFire products:

[image]

I'm using NXP's TapLinx Android api in version 3.0 with this code (the card is detected by the api
`type = libInstance.getCardType(intent);`):

```
        int timeOut = 2000;
        desFireEV3.getReader().setTimeout(timeOut);
        // select master application
        desFireEV3.selectApplication(0);
        // authenticate the master application with the PICC Master Key
        // DES default key
        byte[] TDES_KEY_ZERO = new byte[16]; // 16 bytes
        KeyData objKEY_TDES128ZERO = new KeyData();
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpecTDesZero = new SecretKeySpec(TDES_KEY_ZERO, "TDES");
        objKEY_TDES128ZERO.setKey(secretKeySpecTDesZero);
        desFireEV3.authenticate(0, IDESFireEV3.AuthType.Native, KeyType.THREEDES, objKEY_TDES128ZERO);
        showMessage("authStatus 32: " + desFireEV3.getAuthStatus(), 'n');

        showMessage("change VC Configuration key (0x20)", 'n');
        try {
            byte NEW_KEY_VERSION = (byte) 0x00;
            desFireEV3.changeVCKey(32, new byte[16], new byte[16], NEW_KEY_VERSION);
            showMessage("change VC Configuration key (0x20) done", 'n');
        } catch (UsageException e) {
            showMessage("UsageException: " + e.getMessage(), 'n');
        } catch (InvalidResponseLengthException e) {
            showMessage("InvalidResponseLengthException: " + e.getMessage(), 'n');
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showMessage("Exception: " + e.getMessage(), 'n');
        }
```

Running this code gives these results in Logcat and ends with an **Integrity Error** (0x1E / 30 dec).:

```
NxpLogger               de.androidcrypto.taplinxexample      I  Command sent to card : 5A000000
NxpLogger               de.androidcrypto.taplinxexample      I  Response received : 00
NxpLogger               de.androidcrypto.taplinxexample      I  Command sent to card : 0A00
NxpLogger               de.androidcrypto.taplinxexample      I  Response received : AF0DCA56AAEA80FD9D
NxpLogger               de.androidcrypto.taplinxexample      I  Command sent to card : AF36E119DC9983B9E990AE554DA65151C6
NxpLogger               de.androidcrypto.taplinxexample      I  Response received : 00738F76587001AF44
SampleTapLinx           de.androidcrypto.taplinxexample      I  Dump Data: authStatus 32: Native
NXPLog                  de.androidcrypto.taplinxexample      I  authStatus 32: Native
SampleTapLinx           de.androidcrypto.taplinxexample      I  Dump Data: change VC Configuration key (0x20)
NXPLog                  de.androidcrypto.taplinxexample      I  change VC Configuration key (0x20)
SampleTapLinx           de.androidcrypto.taplinxexample      I  Dump Data: Exception: Integrity Error SW2 = 30
NXPLog                  de.androidcrypto.taplinxexample      I  Exception: Integrity Error SW2 = 30
```

What causes this error and how can I avoid it to change the key successfully ?